# laravel, how to set default value in Validator at post registeration

Tags: php, laravel

I want to set default value for region and country at registration process? I don't want to put hidden inputs or to put it in database or in migration, I want it exactly to be set in registration function

```
 protected function postAdminRegistration(Request $request)
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'fname'     => 'required|string|max:255',
        'lname'     => 'required|string|max:255',
        'country_id'=>'required|integer|min:1',//here default value ex:2
        'region_id'=>'required|integer|min:1',//here default value ex:1
        'email'    => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
    try {
         $validatedData['password']= bcrypt(array_get($validatedData, 'password'));



        $validatedData['activation_code'] = str_random(30).time();
        $user=app(User::class)->create($validatedData);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        logger()->error($exception);
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Unable to create new user.');
    }
    $user->notify(new UserRegisteredSuccessfully($user));
   return Redirect::to("users/login_form")->withSuccess('Successfully created a new account. Please check your email and activate your account.');
```

}

Comment: what does a default value have to do with validation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would just check the value, then reassign the value and null coalescent if it's not there to the default.

```
$validatedData['region_id'] = $validatedData['region_id'] ?? $defaultRegion;
$validatedData['country_id'] = $validatedData['country_id'] ?? $defaultCountry;
```

Usually i would not recommend setting id's through fillables, but set the relationship instead.

```
$user = app(User::class)->create(array_except($validatedData, ['country_id', 'region_id']));

$region = Region::find($validatedData['region_id']) ?? Region::find($defaultRegion);
$user->region()->save($region);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom rule for validation and put your default values and conditions in that check https://laravel-news.com/custom-validation-rule-objects this post, it will clear some basic idea for creating customer rule in Laravel.